# Getting "Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID" when adding AlertDialog in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-jetpack-compose

I'm getting this `Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x108028b` error when adding `AlertDialog` in my app.

I also tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52131284/android-error-cant-find-colorstatelist-from-drawable-resource-while-using-dial), but it didn't help. if `android:statusBarColor` is the issue then this is the code I'm using in my `night\themes.xml`

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
<!--        <item name="statusBarBackground">@color/statusBarDark</item>-->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?android:attr/colorBackground</item>
        <!-- Navigation bar color. -->
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?android:attr/windowBackground</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.AppName.FullscreenContainer" parent="">
        <item name="fullscreenBackgroundColor">@color/light_blue_900</item>
        <item name="fullscreenTextColor">@color/light_blue_A400</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Compose code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AlertDialogSample() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Column {
            val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false)  }

            Button(onClick = {
                openDialog.value = true
            }) {
                Text("Click me")
            }

            if (openDialog.value) {
                AlertDialog(
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        openDialog.value = false
                    },
                    title = {
                        Text(text = "Dialog Title")
                    },
                    text = {
                        Text("Here is a text ")
                    },
                    confirmButton = {
                        Button(
                            onClick = {
                                openDialog.value = false
                            }) {
                            Text("This is the Confirm Button")
                        }
                    },
                    dismissButton = {
                        Button(
                            onClick = {
                                openDialog.value = false
                            }) {
                            Text("This is the dismiss Button")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly is causing this issue, need some help to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear when the error occurs.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti As soon as I open the activity where I want to show the dialog

Comment: Please add composable code which causes your error

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I've attached compose code above in the post

Comment: I was able to reproduce it with your code, but solution from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52131284/android-error-cant-find-colorstatelist-from-drawable-resource-while-using-dial) you were talking about in your question works for me. Maybe you've applied it only to your night theme while testing on a light one?

Comment: Nope, I've applied it on both light and night theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it.

The problem was in below line, not sure why `?android:attr/windowBackground` didn't work but changing to simple `@color/yourColor` solved.

```xml
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">?android:attr/windowBackground</item>
```

Comment: that's exactly what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131757/3585796) is talking about, isn't it?

Comment: Yup, I was just looking at the wrong thing lol

Comment: I see. I suggest you voting for that answer and deleting your question, since it turned out that this is a duplicate